# ASP.NET MVC Hangfire Get Collection of Jobs with details

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jobs, hangfire

I'm using Hangfire in my ASP.NET application to execute methodos in the background but I need to create my own process monitor, so I need to get (select) a collection of Jobs, making filters by date, status, etc ... How can I do this?

Comment: i thought hangfire has a dashboard. Can't that work ?

Comment: @Shyju The dashboard will provide job details for the entire application. I need to make a simple view for my user, so I would need to get a collection of job details.

Answer (score 1):

Use  Hangfire JobStorage

```
var recurringJobs = Hangfire.JobStorage.Current.GetConnection().GetRecurringJobs();
```

You can use this to return from a controller.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var recurringJobs = Hangfire.JobStorage.Current.GetConnection().GetRecurringJobs();
            return View(recurringJobs);
        }
```

Then create your view (Right Click on Index > Add View). This will show the list of views.

Now you can write your script to sort/filter.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to get jobs from database? Hangfire can store them if you configure it in your Startup class.

```
select * from [HangFire].[Job]
```

Comment: Yes, I'm doing the storage on my MongoDb, but I'm working with Code First, I was wondering if Hangfire has a method of accessing this information that already returns me the object as JobDetailsDto.